# Colored dots appear all over the screen in 3D games on RX 5600XT

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, visual-artifacts

I'm having an annoying issue with my PC. I had it a while ago in rdr2, when it suddenly appeared after many hours of playing and now i'm having it in cyberpunk 2077. It looks like colored dots and glares that flicker all over the screen. Then, after a few minutes game simply crashes. Other games seem to work well. I'm pretty sure those are GPU artifacts, but i have no idea about how to fix it. I've tried changing ingame settings, updating drivers and switching to earlier driver version. None of these helped. Any ideas?
My setup:
CPU: ryzen 5 3600;
GPU: Sapphire Pulse RX 5600 xt;
PSU: Chieftec Proton 650w;
RAM: 16 gb;

Here's someone with similar problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iDfww6JtAtE

Comment: The linked video looks like the game is trying to emulate lens flare. Please post your own images, don't use someone else's, whose issue may not be the same.

Comment: No problem, here is it:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UkF-W4zpbUpNILAfx_4lIosDi0ulsDES/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It doesn't look like a 'fail glitch' it looks fully rendered, including glow etc… which I'll admit is odd.